# BizTalk Services SDK

Tags: wcf, sdk, biztalk, firewall, nat

Does anybody has the latest BizTalk Services SDK? I would like to expose the RelayBinding.
I found interesting article about WCF through NATs and firewalls:
http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2007/04/when-you-think-things-are-not-possible-wcf-duplex-callbacks-through-nats-and-firewalls---safe-and-secure.html

Answer (score 0):

The project codename 'BizTalk Services' refers to what is now the [Windows Azure AppFabric](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appfabric/) Sevice Bus. Enjoy!

Comment: I see. BizTalk Services was a cloud-hosted solution, so that part didn't change, other than moving into the Windows Azure hosting environment. There are many other service bus offerings (including Neuron ESB built by my company - http://products.neudesic.com/home). Before you start down any of those paths, figure out what you want a service bus to do for you and where you plan to host it. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm planing a P2P solution without external hosting.

Comment: Maybe I phrased the question poorly. A service bus is a service, it is the rendezvous point for its clients. Rather than having peers know about one another, each peer only needs to know about the service bus. In terms of architecture, where would you want such a service bus to live? That depends on where the peers are and what relationship they have with wherever the service bus is. Perhaps something like Neuron ESB (op. cit.), NServiceBus (http://www.nservicebus.com/) or others would serve you well, depending, of course, on your requirements.